# How to programmatically determine whether a column is set to AUTOINCREMENT in SQLite?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Using Python 2.7's `sqlite3` library, how do I determine which columns of a table are `AUTOINCREMENT`? I know I can use the SQLite command line utility, but how do I do it programmatically. I cursorily looked over the SQLite documentation and the closest `PRAGMA` command I could find was [`table_info`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AUTOINCREMENT` only applies to primary keys. So for a given table, you can use `PRAGMA table_info([tablename])` to determine what column is the primary key:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> conn.execute('CREATE TABLE foo (bar INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, baz)')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10a124f50>
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> c.execute('PRAGMA table_info("foo")')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10a124ef8>
>>> for row in c: print row
... 
(0, u'bar', u'INTEGER', 0, None, 1)
(1, u'baz', u'', 0, None, 0)
>>> [col[0] for col in c.description]
['cid', 'name', 'type', 'notnull', 'dflt_value', 'pk']
```

So the last column in the row is the `pk` row, and for `bar` that is set to `1`.

To determine if the primary key is autoincrementing *at all* you can do one of two things:

1. Query the [`sqlite_master` table](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#sqlite_master) and check if `AUTOINCREMENT` is mentioned in the schema:

   ```
   >>> c.execute('SELECT 1 FROM sqlite_master WHERE tbl_name="foo" AND sql LIKE "%AUTOINCREMENT%"')
   <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10a124ef8>
   >>> c.fetchone()
   (1,)
   ```
2. If you have inserted data, the table name will appear in the [`sqlite_sequence` table](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#intschema):

   ```
   >>> c.execute('insert into foo (baz) values (1)')
   <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10a124ef8>
   >>> c.execute('SELECT 1 FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name="foo"')
   <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10a124ef8>
   >>> c.fetchone()
   (1,)
   ```

Comment: Okay, the first solution in your list is what I needed. The second solution can only check if the table has an `AUTOINCREMENT` attribute. Thank you.

Comment: @AndrewMcKinlay: You don't need the second one if you already know that a table has an `AUTOINCREMENT` column; use it when you need to figure out if there *is* such a column for a given table, use the fist to find *what* column that is. If you are looking at all tables, the two combined will let you list all auto-incrementing columns.